# How can i directory changes and with terminal showing me stay home directory command line?

Tags: command-line

If i want directory changes and with terminal showing me default directory stay ,

when changes directory `khan@raselkhan:~$ cd '/media/khan/Development/Express'` 
then showing me below

```
khan@raselkhan:/media/khan/Development/Express$
```

But , I want directory changes(`/media/khan/Development/Express`) and with terminal showing me like `khan@raselkhan:~$` directory

How i can fix this ?

Comment: do you want to have `khan@raselkhan:~$` as your command prompt for all the times? without changing it to current directory?

Comment: yes, I want changes any directory, command prompt for all the times showing me `khan@raselkhan:~$` like terminal without changing it to current `khan@raselkhan:~$` directory

Answer (score 5):

Edit your `.bashrc` file (`gedit ~/.bashrc`) and change your PS1 there to like as below or add it at the end of the file:

```
PS1='\u@\h:~\$ '
```

Save the file, close and reopen the Terminal or source it again(`. ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.bashrc`) and see the changes.

```
\u - username of the current user (= $LOGNAME),
\h - the name of the computer running the shell (hostname),
\$ - display "$" for normal users and "#" for the root,
@  - display "@"
~  - display "~"
```